# Adding tag fields to a model's new and edit forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using Rails 3.0.1 and the acts-as-taggable-on gem.

I have it implemented properly (I can create and find tags for my Post model in the rails console.)

I even have the tag cloud working on my controller's index page.

I am stuck on the part I wasn't expecting to get stuck on. :(

How do I add the text_field for the tag list to the new and edit view forms when adding a new Post or editing a current one? For some reason, probably because I am daft, I can find no examples of this in my searches--I am the only one who can't figure it out!

So, don't hold back. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acts-as-taggable-on expects a plain input field to enter the coma separated tags. If your model has `acts_as_taggable`, the view will be something like the following code (locate your own in `_form.html.erb` partial):

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_list %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

if has `acts_as_taggable_on :languages` will be:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :language_list %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :language_list %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I had, I think. I must have had a problem somewhere else in my code. But it is good to know that I can add the other lists like you showed with :languages. Thanks for the great answer.